# Return not matching rows after joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am not sure how to ask this correctly, but here it is:

**table1**

```
id   |    email
---------------------------
1         test@test.com
---------------------------
2         random@test.com
---------------------------
3         magic@test.com
---------------------------
4         example@test.com
---------------------------
5         noreply@test.com
---------------------------
6         admin@test.com
---------------------------
7         editor@test.com
```

**table2**

```
id   |    email_two
---------------------------
7         test@test.com
---------------------------
10        random@test.com
---------------------------
33        magic@test.com
---------------------------
99        example@test.com
---------------------------
109       master@test.com
---------------------------
299       blaster@test.com
```

**Question:**

How to correctly join two tables, and get not matching results by email? For example, what i need to get from both tables is:

```
noreply@test.com
admin@test.com
editor@test.com
master@test.com
blaster@test.com
```

because other emails matching each other.

**Code**

```
SELECT email_two FROM table2 b WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 a WHERE a.email = b.email_two
```

This code returns only missing ones from table2, but i cant find a correct way to return missing results from two tables in one query.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most suitable operation for what you want is a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which is unfortunately not supported in MySQL.

You can use `UNION ALL` instead:

```
SELECT email_two AS email
FROM table2 b 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 a 
                  WHERE a.email = b.email_two)

UNION ALL

SELECT email 
FROM table1 a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 b 
                  WHERE a.email = b.email_two)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use LEFT JOIN and UNION ALL to get this, below is sample query that may help you to get these records.

```
select t1.email as 'email'  from  t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.email = t2.email
where t2.email is null
UNION ALL
select t2.email as 'email'  from  t2 LEFT JOIN t1 on t2.email = t1.email 
where t1.email is null;
```